# Big white space on right side of website

Tags: css

I started to do the example picture part of my new project and then suddenly this big white space appeared on the right hand side and it is making it also very frustrating to center my pictures. I am pretty new to this and learning as I go along.

http://sleeksurvey.com/

Comment: Because you are using margin-left:445px in .section-examples

Comment: Just remove float:left from .section-examples and do margin-left:auto and you are done.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Okay I done that and now the orange horizontal line below is taking up the full page and still white space on the right.

Comment: can you please update your code so i can see that issue on site as i can see container is in middle with no error after my edits.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just done it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using it wrong. Just remove `margin-left:445px` and make it `margin-left:auto` and remove `float:left` from .section-examples class and your images(section) will be in center.

**UPDATED**

In above container you are using box div inside row then why you are using that div outside in 3rd section?? Just simply cut that box folder and put inside second div (row) of image section and you are done :)

Comment: Downvote?? Guyz can you please comment why downvote when answer is crystal clear??